# How to convert this one-liner asm to C

Tags: assembly, decompilation, c

I want to convert this to C:

```
SHR CL,1
```

rECX is the name of the (32bit unsigned int)register variable. It should be simple, but I can't figure out the proper pointer magic :/

Comment: `*(unsigned char*)&rECX >>= 1;` I knew it was easy :)

Comment: Folks, please don't forget to vote up questions, too! Although this would likely be more fitting for SO, it's a valid question that internauts may find useful. Voting will help it pop up more prominently and reward the asker.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`rECX = (rECX & 0xFFFFFF00) | ((rECX & 0xFF) >> 1)`